# VSTO Project: 'Sub Main' not found after changing Project Assembly Name

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vsto

I received above mentioned  error after changing my project assembly name in Project > Properties > Application > Assembly Name

Any Ideas how to solve it?

I already tried these 2 solutions but none of them worked:

1-Right clicked on my project name in solution explorer and clicked on **"Set as Startup Project"**

2-Tried to set **Startup Project** in my project properties page but it is grayed out.

3-Change my Target Framework from 4 to 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

I also mistakenly had changed my **Application Type** from **Class Library** to **Windows Form Application** so changing it back to **Class** solved my problem.